# Swing - Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: swing

I tried some swing today for a GUI in java. When I want to launch the application, this error appears. Here is my source code:

```
package de.hoffmann;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainApplication extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MainApplication() {

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Buchstaben-Häufigkeit");
        mainFrame.setSize(600,400);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);

        mainFrame.add(panel);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MainApplication().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Where's the problem

Comment: i tried your code, it works, i can see the window which error do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. I suggest you to set the dimension of panel object: 
`panel.setSize(600,400);`
and set the mainFrame to visible: `mainFrame.setVisible(true);`. If you have a Java heap space problem, which I find strange however, have a look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)